# MSSQL Query exceeding allowed memory in php

Tags: php, sql-server

I have a query that uses stuff() when using it in PHP it fails due to it running out of memory.

the error occurs on this line;

```
$data = odbc_exec($conn, $query);
```

at this point php doesn't actually receive any data it is just assigning a network resource. the connection is fine, i use it everywhere else, and the query strlen is only ~400.

so what is actually going on here?

```
select oeename.id, oeename.Name, stuff( 
    (select distinct ', ' + departmentequipment.name from type join DepartmentEquipment on departmentequipmentfk = departmentequipment.id where type.OEENameFK = oeename.ID order by ', ' + departmentequipment.name for xml path('')) ,1,1,'') as departmentequipmentnames 
from oeename order by oeename.name asc
```

even when i add top 1 to the query the query still exceeds the memory limit.

EDIT: the php script was working before, someone had detected a bug in a somewhat related part of my website and upon attempting to fault find the issue i came across this problem on my local development server. the table is now partly larger, but its failing on exec rather than reading the data in.

Comment: Are you saying you have no issues running the query in SSMS, for example?

Comment: indeed, the query runs fine in SSMS

Comment: Do you see any spikes in memory on your machine or on the SQL server when you run the query? Is your PHP environment on a different box with less memory?

Comment: it completes in under a second, completes nearly instantly. the point being i can't really capture anything about its performance because it completes so fast. the sql server and apache server are on different machines

Comment: Also, have you tried using a more dedicated, robust, and preferred library for data access, such as PDO (PHP Data Objects)? (To eliminate issues with ODBC drivers.)

Comment: Maybe you're running into this bug: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68964

Comment: changing the driver doesn't seem a viable solution, i will look into changing the version of php though and get back to you. i have also updated the original post to include more information

Comment: changing the php version did nothing.

Comment: It would appear casting the stuff to varchar(max) fixes the issue. this would indicate that the bug you found is responsible. Cory, if you want to post an answer ill mark it as correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you're running into this bug: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=68964

To summarize the workaround, you need to cast any `ntext` fields to `nvarchar(max)` instead.